# In iOS, Is GestureRecogizer target action running in a separate thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here is the problem, on the UI of my iPhone app, I have a button and another imageView that accepts Touch gesture recognizer, both have target actions. If I touch the button and the view one at a time, everything is fine. But if I touch these 2 simultaneously, or in rapid succession, things get messed up. The button and gesture handler manipulate the same state variables, so if they run side by side, the result is non-deterministic.

I tried to fix this problem by disabling the button the instant I get into gesture recognizer handler, and enabling it right before exiting the handler. But this doesn't solve my problem!!!

So the only possibility (my guess) is that the gesture recognizer gets triggered when the button handler is running. But this could only happen if they resides in separate threads. So does anyone know if the gesture recognizer handler is running in a different thread? Or, more specific to my problem, what should I do in my situation? Use guard variables to prevent conflict?

Comment: Can you post any of the code from both of the handlers?

Comment: I figured out the problem: disabling the button doesn't help if I tap the button and the image at the same time, because the button event get fired before it is disabled; and since my gesture handler uses a timer to do something after 1 second, the button handler gets called in that second and get things wrong. I end up using guard variable to solve this.
But the question here is still valid, does anyone know if gesture recognizer handlers get called in the same thread as main UI or another thread. .

Comment: They are called on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in the class that implement the delegate of gesture recognizer

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}`